# How to Run a subroutine from a different project from my active workbook? VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Here is my scenario:

- I open my calculator "DR Calculator.xlsm" from my own spreadsheet "Howie.xlsm"
- From "Howie.xlsm I would like to run the subroutine `Button_ClickClear` found in "DR Calculator"
- I have tried the following:

  ```
  Windows("DR Calculator.xlsm").Activate 
  Run Macro:="C:\Users\rchun1\Documents\Demand\DR Calculator\'DR  Calculator.xlsm'!Button5_ClickClear"
  ```
- I get the following error:

  ```
  Cannot run the macro 'C:\Users\rchun1\Documents\Demand\DR Calculator\'DR Calculator.xlsm'!Button5_ClickClear'. 
  The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.
  ```
- I have enabled all macros in all excel files by messing with the Trust Center and tried messing with the references found in tools.

Sources that I have tried:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2003-customize/how-do-i-call-a-procedure-from-a-module-in-a/5e8645a6-3739-4fcc-be13-52e216f7961f?auth=1
http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=80137

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Application.Run "'DR Calculator.xlsm'!Button5_ClickClear"
```

Comment: It worked! I guess the spaces the syntax is what killed me there. Thanks Tim!